# Current version of "Using mod_ssl on Mac OS X" documentation?

Tags: apache, macos, ssl, mod-ssl

I'm fairly new to Mac I want to enable SSL on my Mac (10.6.4) for some local development.  In searching for an answer, I ran across [Using mod_ssl on Mac OS X](http://developer.apple.com/internet/serverside/modssl.html).  However, this Apple developer support document looked out of date.  In further searching, I ran across [Configuring mod_ssl on Mac OS Snow Leopard](http://www.entropy.ch/phpbb2/viewtopic.php?t=5321&sid=70668edf16069bc0eaef44eb8cc3fe46) which basically asked the same question I am asking, but had no replies.  It stated those instructions for were for "*Mac 10.2/Apache 1.3*" and not for a "*Mac 10.6/Apache 2*" system.

I've worked with Apache before, but never configured SSL.  I am sure I will figure it out, but I thought I would ask here first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the changes I made to `/private/etc/apache2/http.conf`

Updated this line to include my email address

```
ServerAdmin you@example.com
```

Uncommented this line, and made sure it matched my servername (e.g. XXX.local)

```
#ServerName www.example.com:80
```

Uncommented this line

```
#Include /private/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-ssl.conf
```

In `/private/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-ssl.conf` I also updated `ServerAdmin` and `ServerName` and copied my .crt and .key to the locations configured in the file.

```
SSLCertificateFile "/private/etc/apache2/server.crt"
SSLCertificateKeyFile "/private/etc/apache2/server.key"
```